# PHP / MySQL - Getting last 3 uniquely updated records

Tags: php, mysql

Im wondering if someone could help out.

I need to write a query that gets the last 3 'created' records, but their UID has to be unique so for example, my mysql fields look like so

```
uid    created
19     2012-02-01 01:08:43
18     2012-02-31 17:07:21
19     2012-02-31 16:07:20
20     2012-02-31 13:03:00
```

Ok, so i want to get the last 3 uid's created ... but they have to be unique uid's so the same uid cant appear twice.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

this should do this

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY uid, created DESC ) ordered GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: That works, except its not ordering them by the date 'created'

Answer (score 0):

You can select last 3 IDs with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY uid, created DESC ) AS selected GROUP BY uid LIMIT 3
```

Logic is: order table by uid field in descending and limit to 3 fields.

Comment: oh, sorry my mistake. I missed that uid is no primary key. Here is the right answer: `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY uid, created DESC ) AS selected GROUP BY uid` LIMIT 3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY created DESC 
GROUP BY uid LIMIT 0,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Distinct and Group by to get what you're after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table GROUP BY uid;
```

That will give you all unique UID's.
Then add your ORDER BY in there to make sure you grab the last records.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table GROUP BY uid ORDER BY created DESC; this seems to work perfect :)

Comment: but ORDER BY orders result after GROUP BY, so it will group them by `uid` and then order them by `created`, but that grouped result doesn't have to have latest created `uid`s

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uid
     , MAX(created) AS max_created
FROM tableX
GROUP BY uid
ORDER BY max_created DESC
LIMIT 3
```